# Start firefox browser in maximized form - Selenium Webdriver

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I wanted to ask if there is a way in selenium webdriver to initiate the firefox driver in maximized form.

I know `driver.manage().window().maximize();` will do the job, but with this the browser is opened in restored form and after couple of seconds it goes to maximized form. What I want is to open the browser in maximized instantly when my test runs. ChromeOptions works for chrome browser like following,

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "chromedriver.exe");
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
            options.addArguments("--start-maximized");
            driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

Is there a similar way for firefox as well?

Comment: already you maximize it before execute your test step. so where is the problem exactly?

Comment: @MahsumAkbas the problem is that for firefox it initially open the browser in restored state and after couple of seconds it maximizes it, but with the chromeOptions, I can initiate the chrome browser in maximized form, there is no delay in that. I am asking if there is a similar way for firefox as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that you will not find anything better than `driver.manage().window().maximize();`.

Look at this workitem. It was raised 10 years ago.

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=873618